# C program Maze game traversal in multidimensional array having trouble figuring out how to check if user input is a valid move in the maze

Tags: c

In the switch statement, I need some way to check if the '0' character is making a valid move into a ' '(empty space in maze) and not into a '*' (wall). If the user tries to make an invalid move then it ignores that move and moves on to the next loop. In my switch statement, cases A, D, and S successfully make '0' move through the maze. When I try to implement this if statement I have in case W, the output still moves the '0' character and will print "W action not allowed".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printMaze(char MAZE[50][50]);

int main(void) 
{
  int yValue = 9;
  int xValue = 0;
  char movement; 

  char MAZE[50][50] =
  {
    {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'0',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' '},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' '},
    {'*',' ','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*',' ',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*',' ','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*',' ','*','*','*','*','*'},
    {'*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','*'},
    {'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'}};

    //printMaze(MAZE);
    while(1){
      printMaze(MAZE);
      printf("Enter direction you want to move \nA(left)\nS(down)\nD(right)\nW(up)\n");
      movement = getchar();
      switch(movement){
        case 'A' :
        case 'a' :
        //player is moving character to the left
            printf("A action executed\n");
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
            xValue --;
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
            break;


        case 'D' :
        case 'd' :
        //player is moving character to the right
            printf("D action executed\n");
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
            xValue ++;
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
            break;


        case 'S' :
        case 's' :
        //player is moving character down
            printf("S action executed\n");
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
            yValue ++;
            MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0';
            break;



        case 'W' :
        case 'w' :
        //player is moving character up
          if(MAZE[yValue -- ][xValue] == ' '){
              printf("W action executed\n");
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
              yValue --;
              MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0'; 
              break;
          }
          printf("W action not allowed");
          break;

      }
    }
}
void printMaze(char MAZE[][50])
{
  for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
  {
    for(int y = 0; y < 50; y++)
    {
      printf("%c ", MAZE[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just put the "action not allowed" printing in an `else` branch? Like

```
if(MAZE[yValue - 1][xValue] == ' '){
    printf("W action executed\n");
    MAZE[yValue][xValue] = ' ';
    yValue --;
    MAZE[yValue][xValue] = '0'; 
}else{
    printf("W action not allowed");
}
break;
```

Do note that I changed `MAZE[yValue -- ]` to `MAZE[yValue - 1]`. Otherwise you will decrement `yValue` *twice*.

I also recommend that you add some checks for indexes going out of bounds as well. For example by adding a `yValue > 0` check:

```
if(yValue > 0 && MAZE[yValue - 1][xValue] == ' '){
```

And of course that you do the same checks for all the cases.

---

Also note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`, which is very important if you want to check for error or end-of-file (which you always should do).